# Multiple activiti ldap configurations

Tags: ldap, activiti

I have a problem and maybe somebody can help me. In my corporation we are using activiti 5.17 and we have two different ldap servers, server1 and server2 and we need to authenticate against server1 and if user is not there then authenticate against server 2. I had been searching for some solution but it 
seems that nobody has this problem. Can you guys give me a light about how can a solve this problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you will need to tweak the Activiti LDAP integration to meet your needs of double authentication. Luckily for you Activiti is Open Source so you can change and improve that implementation :)

Comment: Yes you are right, but i need some help about what exactly i have to do in activiti code to solve my problem

Comment: Which version are you using?